# Is Theorem 4.4 in Borel[1976] also true for covering group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Theorem 4.4 in [Borel - Admissible representations of a semi-simple group over a local field with vectors fixed under an Iwahori subgroup](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390139) claims that the induced module $I(E)$ and coinduced module $P(E)$ are admissible $G$-modules if $(r,E)$ is a finite dimensional $H(G,B)$-module, where $H(G,B)$ is the Iwahori–Hecke algebra.

The proof of theorem 4.4 used a lemma on buildings and I don't know if it is also right for covering group.

Is it true that $I(E)$ and $P(E)$ are genuine admissible $\widetilde{G}$-modules if $(r,E)$ is a finite dimensional  $H^{\epsilon}(\widetilde{G},B)$-module?

Is there any reference and is theorem 4.4 true for an $n$-fold covering group $\widetilde{\operatorname{SL}_{2}(F)}$ over a $p$-adic field $F$?